# PDO prepared statement returns not correct lastInsertId

Tags: php, mysql, modx, last-insert-id, xpdo

My head is close to explode.

I'm trying to insert a lot of rows to database using prepared statements (it's MODx cms).

Query looks like:

```
INSERT INTO {$table} (`fio`, `address`, `code`) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
   fio = VALUES(fio),
   address = VALUES(address),
   code = VALUES(code),
   `eid` = LAST_INSERT_ID(eid);
```

Next step is

```
foreach ( $data as $k=>$v){
   $q->execute(array($v['fio'], $v['address'], $v['code']));
   $eid = $this->modx->lastInsertId('eid');
}
```

And I have some rows in the table, that were filled before. When I'm trying to execute the script, only the first $eid is correct and points to an existing row. Every next value of $eid is more than even AUTO_INCREMENT value for the table.

Tried different variants, but $eid is correct only when I'm deleting prepared statement and using a usual query.

Help please...

Comment: Don't think you need the parameter in `lastInsertId('eid');`, try `lastInsertId();`

Comment: Tried, the same result.

Comment: when executing prepared statement, the id of the last insered value will be in the insert_id. Try follwing this->modx->lastInsertId($q->insert_id) and pass its value to your on duplicate code.

Comment: Not helped, still returning ids like: 
61
16919
54912
54914
54916
54918
54920
...

Comment: And $q->insert_id returns nothing.